# Where the error 'Content is not allowed in prolog' comes from?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

For example in Problems I have

> Content is not allowed in prolog.

How to find out why its there(what eclipse plugin has put it there) and how to turn it off?

Comment: Have you got a malformed xml file somewhere?  Possibly with some text before the opening angle bracket...

Comment: no, its not that. just some xhtml does not work in that eclipse. they are ok, eclipse has a bug.

Comment: can anyone tell me where i can vote down users?

Comment: @Chris: You don't enough reputation (yet) to do that.

Comment: thanks. such a shame... i'll bookmark this question so that i dont forget to vote this down

Comment: @IAdapter: And you should know how to ask a proper question by now. Quit being a bully.

Comment: @Chris You're now good to go. Each downvote costs 1 rep. Don't be too vindictive!

Comment: @Chris: You aren't supposed to downvote *users*. You downvote (and upvote) individual questions and answers. It doesn't have anything to do with how much you like the person behind them.

Comment: I know but if the question is that unclear that even the creator doesn't understand it and he votes all the answers down which he think doesn't answer his question correctly it's worth 1 of my reputation points :-)

Comment: The relevant canonical question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138696/org-xml-sax-saxparseexception-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem too and it was, because i changed/saved the file in UltraEdit. After the save command, the file encoding changed and included characters, eclipse was not able to read.

You can open the file with the windows "Editor" tool and delete the characters, eclipse can not read. You will directly detect them.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like an error with a xml file. Most of the time "Content is not allowed in prolog" means, that your XML file does not have the right format or even doesn't start the right way.

Comment: You wrote "How to find out why its there" !!

Answer (score 3):

"Content is not allowed in prolog" is the error thrown by Xerces when there's something in an XML file or stream that precedes the `<?xml?>` declaration. There must be nothing before that, not even whitespace or a Byte-Order-Mark.

Comment: @IAdapter: You also asked "why it's there". If you want help from people, stop being so snippy.

Answer (score 2):

Double-click the message and it should take you to the file (and ideally location within the file) that is the source of the problem.

This specific error sounds like you've got a malformed XML file.

Comment: no, it doesnt work. for example in warning I only have file, line and desc. I don't know why its there.