# Error in importing Eclipse project in android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

While importing the project in Android Studio I am getting an error saying

> Invalid XML file: C:\XXXXXXX\AndroidManifest.xml: Content is not
>   allowed in prolog.

How to resolve this? Please help me regarding this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445143/eclipse-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog

Comment: Can you please share your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Check `AndroidManifest.xml` file, 2 problems might occur :

1. your header `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>` is
   incorrect
2. there is a string right before it : `afaf<?xml version .....`

Answer (score 0):

This error message is always caused by the invalid XML content in the beginning element.

More info [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/sax-error-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog/)