# "Content is not allowed in prolog." error in clustered server

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, facelets

We have an instance running with two clustered servers at oracle web logic app server.

One of the servers runs smoothly, but the other gives the error at the login page.

I checked the logs but got nothing, any idea where to look?

login page error:

```
com.sun.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /content/templates/baseLayout.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 1] Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:234)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:105)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:197)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:144)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:293)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:274)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:145)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:113)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:248)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:295)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:274)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:145)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:113)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:96)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.buildView(FaceletViewHandler.java:525)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:567)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:101)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfView.render(JsfView.java:94)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.ViewFactoryActionAdapter.doExecute(ViewFactoryActionAdapter.java:40)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.EndState.doEnter(EndState.java:101)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:195)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.start(Flow.java:536)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:350)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:221)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.launchExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:141)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:502)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:821)
    at company.middleware.web.servlets.ServletToBeanProxy.service(ServletToBeanProxy.java:47)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:302)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:390)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:517)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:265)
    at company.middleware.web.filters.CurrentUserFilterInvocationDefinitionsSessionIntegrationFilter.doFilter(CurrentUserFilterInvocationDefinitionsSessionIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:265)
    at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107)
    at company.middleware.security.flow.ReportFlowIdAwareFilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(ReportFlowIdAwareFilterSecurityInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    at org.acegisecurity.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:82)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:272)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:111)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    at company.middleware.web.filters.CurrentFlowIdSessionIntegrationFilter.doFilter(CurrentFlowIdSessionIntegrationFilter.java:57)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    at company.middleware.web.filters.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:98)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:150)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    at company.middleware.web.filters.BypassAcegiAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BypassAcegiAuthenticationFilter.java:99)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    at company.middleware.web.filters.AppUrlPreAppendingResponseWrapperFilter.doFilter(AppUrlPreAppendingResponseWrapperFilter.java:33)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    at company.middleware.web.filters.IECompatibilityFixFilter.doFilter(IECompatibilityFixFilter.java:33)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:150)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:99)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at company.middleware.web.filters.Log4JNDCFilter.doFilter(Log4JNDCFilter.java:55)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:99)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
```

Comment: just a suggestion, you should check your xhtml encoding. And also do you have this line "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>" at your xhtml first line?

Comment: Have you verified your baseLayout.xhtm don't have any strange characters before your `<?xml…..>` declaration ? The `Content is not allowed in prolog` message sometimes is caused by the invalid XML content in the beginning element.

Comment: If one server works but the other does not, the two servers could XHTML be subtly different. The templates could bd different. Perhaps they have different encodings, or one has a BOM.

Comment: The canonical question about the exception is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138696/org-xml-sax-saxparseexception-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog

Answer (score 8):

Your file /content/templates/baseLayout.xhtml has probably got something dodgy in the first line - it should be something like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`