# I'm using Jena to import a skos thesaurus and it doesn't work

Tags: xml, rdf, jena

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138696/org-xml-sax-saxparseexception-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog)

I would like to import a skos (rdf/xml) thesaurus in Jena model. The skos thesaurus is available in http://www.culturaitalia.it/pico/thesaurus/4.2/thesaurus_4.2.0.skos.xml. I copied that to a local file (in picoFileName) and I used this code to import it in a Model:

```
    ...
    pico = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(picoFileName);
    if (in == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "File: " + picoFileName + " not found");
    }
    pico.read(new InputStreamReader(in), "");
    ...
```

I receive this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.JenaException:   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.RDFDefaultErrorHandler.fatalError(RDFDefaultErrorHandler.java:60)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.ARPSaxErrorHandler.fatalError(ARPSaxErrorHandler.java:51)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.XMLHandler.warning(XMLHandler.java:211)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.XMLHandler.fatalError(XMLHandler.java:241)
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.impl.RDFXMLParser.parse(RDFXMLParser.java:155)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.JenaReader.read(JenaReader.java:173)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.JenaReader.read(JenaReader.java:160)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.JenaReader.read(JenaReader.java:199)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.read(ModelCom.java:229)
at it.etc.rdf.LodWithPico.<init>(LodWithPico.java:24)
at it.etc.rdf.TestLodWithPico.main(TestLodWithPico.java:6)
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
... 18 more
```

The skos thesaurus is validated in w3c rdf/xml validator and in skos validator. What is wrong?

Comment: sorry I didn't understand what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, there was something wrong in the input file. I copied file content in an other file and it works.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is in "picoFileName"?  Works for me if I call a parser on the downloaded content.
Which version of Jena is this?

Comment: In picoFileName there is the file full path, and it works because it doesn't throw IllegalArgumentException: I followed it with debug and the crash statement is: pico.read(new InputStreamReader(in), "");