# Tomcat ExpiresFilter not working correctly

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I can't get Tomcat to send images with the correct expires definition. The browser keep sending get requests for images already downloaded and Tomcat responds with 304. What I would want is that Tomcat will respond to the initial request with proper expires header and without any Last-modified header so the browser will use local cache until the file expires without going to the server each page load to see if the image had changed.

I have the following definition in my web.xml file:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ExpiresByType image</param-name>
        <param-value>access plus 1 weeks</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ExpiresByType text/css</param-name>
        <param-value>modification plus 0 minutes</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ExpiresByType application/javascript</param-name>
        <param-value>modification plus 0 minutes</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 6):

Can you enabled ExpiresFilter logs as described in [Container Provided Filters > ExpiresFilter  > Troubleshooting](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Troubleshooting) :

Add to `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/logging.properties` the following declaration:

```
org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter.level = FINE
```

You will see log message such as the following:

An expiration header is added:

```
Mar 26, 2010 2:09:47 PM org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter onBeforeWriteResponseBody
  FINE: Request "/tomcat.gif" with response status "200"
  content-type "image/gif", set expiration date 3/26/10 2:19 PM
```

No expiration header is added:

```
Mar 26, 2010 2:10:27 PM org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter onBeforeWriteResponseBody
  FINE: Request "/docs/config/manager.html" with response status "200"
  content-type "text/html", no expiration configured
```

Comment: Same problem here. I've put the logs as you said, and the error line I receive is:
05-Aug-2019 10:48:31.689 FINE [http-apr-80-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter.isEligibleToExpirationHeaderGeneration Request "/docs/es/" with response status "304" content-type "304", skip expiration header generation for given status
I don't understand.... precisely the status 304 is what I wanted to avoid.