# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, xml, xmldog

I had this exception

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 39; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at jlibs.xml.sax.dog.XMLDog.sniff(XMLDog.java:188)
```

when using [XMLDog](https://code.google.com/p/jlibs/wiki/XMLDog) `sniff()` method.

My Java code is

```java
String xml = "..."
XPathResults results = xmlDog.sniff(new InputSource(new StringInputStream(xml)));
```

as you can see I have my XML in String, so there is no problem with UTF-8 BOF, also I'm sure that there are no whitespaces in `xml` string...

Comment: Probably there is a ByteStream somewhere in there and you are getting a different character encoding when the string is decoded and when the bytestream is later re-encoded.

Comment: Correction: an InputStream *is* a stream of bytes, so there could definitely be encoding issues.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138696/org-xml-sax-saxparseexception-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I found later was, that I used StringInputStream class and didn't realize, that it is `org.hsqldb.lib.StringInputStream.StringInputStream(String)`.

When I replaced this one with

- `java.io.StringBufferInputStream.StringBufferInputStream(String)` // deprecated
- or `java.io.StringReader.StringReader(String)` // sniff accepts reader too
- or `java.io.ByteArrayInputStream.ByteArrayInputStream(byte[])`

...it worked. I didn't investigate why the previous one from hsqldb package is bad in this case...