# Logging a ByteBuffer value, but now I want to get the original String (an XML) from that ByteBuffer

Tags: java, xml, bytebuffer

How can I do that?

I tried this:

```
        String a = "my_byte_buffer_copied_from_my_logs";
        value = ByteBuffer.wrap(a.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); 

        InputStream callbackRequest = new ByteArrayInputStream(value.array());    
        return jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(callbackRequest);
```

But it fails with this message:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

Which seems to indicate that the [XML is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138696/org-xml-sax-saxparseexception-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog)

FYI, I know that the encoding UTF-8 is correct.

Comment: Do you have a BOM?

Comment: How can I know if I have a BOM or not? Because the XML is represented as a ByteBuffer (which is then logged as a string). The value starts with 'PD94' then I have like 400 bytes and it ends with 'bnQ+'..... @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: Check for the corresponding bytes at the beginning of the buffer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: I don't think I have it, according to the wiki, the BOM should be "EF BB BF" in hex.... @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: What are the first 3 bytes in the buffer?

Comment: '504' @SotiriosDelimanolis in hex, but the String value is 'PD9'

Comment: I don't understand that representation. Are you saying the first three bytes are 5, 0, and 4? Please show us how you're determining that. There's no byte value 504.

Comment: I did an 'xxd file' and the first line 0000000: 5044 3934 6257 7767 646d 5679 6332 6c76 @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: That doesn't look like XML to me. You obviously aren't receiving what you expected.