# How to parse multiple xmls from a list?

Tags: java, xml, parsing

Hi I am trying to parse multiple xml's from a list, but every time I get same exact data instead of different data my list contain.getLatestNYData() provides me the xmls (10 suppose) and I am storng them in to. Now I need to parse all those xml's that is why I am looping through them and storing them in reqXML.

Code.

```
public List<NYProgramTO> getNYPPAData() throws Exception{
    this.getConfiguration();
    List<NYProgramTO> to = dao.getLatestNYData();
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    try {
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource source = new InputSource();

        String reqXML = "<servers>";
        for(NYProgramTO nyProgram: to){
            reqXML += nyProgram.getRequestXML();
        }
        reqXML = "</servers>";
        source.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(reqXML));

        Document document = builder.parse(source);

        NodeList list = document.getElementsByTagName("server");
        for(int iterate = 0; iterate < list.getLength(); iterate++){
            Node node = list.item(iterate);

            if(node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                Element element = (Element) node;

                for(NYProgramTO nyP : to ){
                    nyP.setFirstName(element.getElementsByTagName("FirstName").item(0).getTextContent());
                    nyP.setLastName(element.getElementsByTagName("LastName").item(0).getTextContent());
                    nyP.setPolicyNumber(element.getElementsByTagName("PolicyNumber").item(0).getTextContent());
                    nyP.setZipCode(element.getElementsByTagName("ZipCode").item(0).getTextContent());
                    nyP.setDateOfBirth(element.getElementsByTagName("BirthDate").item(0).getTextContent());
                }

                this.writeToExcel(to);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return to;
}
```

So every time reqXML is updated but then how can I achieve all those 10 xmls. Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: can you give an example of the xml you get from nyProgram.getRequestXML();

Comment: What is the case against using the simplified for loop? Too new?

Answer (score 0):

**Cause**

when you do

```
for(NYProgramTO nyProgram: to){
    String reqXML = nyProgram.getRequestXML();
    source.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(reqXML));
}
```

you overwrite the source character stream at every iteration. So only the last one is written.

You need to build the whole XML in the loop and call the `source.setCharacterStream` outside of the loop.

**Solution**

Given that each XML bit is of the form

```
<server><requests>.......</server></request>
```

This should work:

```
String reqXML = "<servers>";
for(NYProgramTO nyProgram: to){
    reqXML += nyProgram.getRequestXML();
}
reqXML += "</servers>"
source.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(reqXML));
```

**Regarding your parsing issue**

I tried that code:

```
try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource source = new InputSource();

        String reqXML =
            "<servers>" +
            "  <server>" +
            "    <FirstName>Nicolas</FirstName>" +
            "  </server>" +
            "  <server>" +
            "    <FirstName>Peter</FirstName>" +
            "  </server>" +
            "</servers>";

    source.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(reqXML));

    Document document = builder.parse(source);

    NodeList list = document.getElementsByTagName("server");
    for(int iterate = 0; iterate < list.getLength(); iterate++){
        Node node = list.item(iterate);

        if(node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
            Element element = (Element) node;

            String firstName = element.getElementsByTagName("FirstName").item(0).getTextContent();
            System.out.println(firstName);
        }
    }

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

And  it works, printing out Nicolas and Peter as expected. So I think your XML is not well formed, can you add the XML you get in `reqXML`? There might be unwanted characters in the XML. See this question [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138696/org-xml-sax-saxparseexception-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog)

Indeed, If I use the follwoing XML (adding an unwanted character before the first tag) in my example above I get the same error as you `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.`

```
String reqXML =
        "t<servers>" +
        "  <server>" +
        "    <FirstName>Nicolas</FirstName>" +
        "  </server>" +
        "  <server>" +
        "    <FirstName>Peter</FirstName>" +
        "  </server>" +
        "</servers>";
```

Comment: Thanks Bentaye for the response. getRequestXML() gives me a long XML payload. So basically form multiple xml files I am reading some tags so in this I expect 10 different names form 10 different xml's . Hope it is clear.

Comment: @David Can you try my solution, and if it does not work, tell me what you expect differently

Comment: Now I am getting this exception org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.

Comment: I edited the example code to surround the XML with a <servers> tag. Would it work better ?

Comment: I get this error now: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
Document document = builder.parse(source); in this line. I have added this lne in my question

Comment: I have posted the complete method I wrote.

Comment: I don't have time right now, but I will have a look tomorrow if you don't get the solution by then.

Comment: @David I added some remarks to the answer, I think your XML is simply malformed somehow. Your code works for me.