# Execution failed for task ':app:extractDeepLinksDebug'

Tags: java

I'm getting the error

Execution failed for task ':app:extractDeepLinksDebug'.

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.

I'm not sure which file has the problem so can someone please tell me

Comment: The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138696/org-xml-sax-saxparseexception-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog) will be the solution to your question.

Comment: I'm new to java so its a bit hard to understand what people mean

Comment: I think you have an `xml` file. There is an error in this `xml` file, this is what you need to solve.

Answer (score -1):

it's give an error on xml files scheme to Uri  is not registered even if White space

in this line please verify that
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`